# How to create an Azure Website programmatically using Azure PowerShell commands in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell, azure

I found all Azure Management Cmdlets here:

[Windows Azure Management Cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152841.aspx).

My question is how can I use these cmdlets in C# to create, remove and deploy an Azure Website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without azure login we can not fire any command. We can Create Website in following steps.

1. Login to AzureAccount (Add-AzureAccount)
2. Setup The Azure Subscription (Get-AzureSubscription)
3. Select Azure Subscription (Select-AzureSubscription -Name AzureSubName)
4. Then We Can Deploy Azure site here

Ref to deploy site : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/04/23/azure-powershell-azure-websites-for-the-command-line-junkies-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure managemnet cmdlets have been updated and now it includes web site creation. Check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152841.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the samples from my book, PowerShell for Developers.

This example embeds the PowerShell engine in a C# application. You can then call the Azure PowerShell cmdlets and/or external PowerShell scripts that contain the workflow that you develop.

http://goo.gl/4kiYa